# Add a parent to an abstract class so it is no longer abstract

Tags: java

say I have an interface and a class:

```
    public static interface Businessman { public void workHard(); }

    public static class CTO implements Businessman {}
```

What parent should I create for CTO that it will no longer be abstract?

Comment: Uh, nothing? `CTO` isn't `abstract` to begin with (in this example at least)... Is there perhaps a different example you could provide?

Comment: An Interface in Java cannot be static. Also, a class cannot be static unless it is nested. Sounds like you need to read up a bit on the basics before understanding what your trying to do.

Comment: @Jason: Well said. But I think nested interfaces also can be static.

Comment: @Syam nice catch! I actually was not aware of nested interface, maybe I too need to brush up on basics :). I found that nested interfaces are implicitly static regardless of where they are declared. Hope someone finds this helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want the compiler to complain about `CTO` not being abstract, you can make a default ("do-nothing") implementation of `Businessman` from which `CTO` inherits:

```
// DefaultBusinessman.java
public class DefaultBusinessman implements Businessman {
    @Override
    public void workHard() {
    }
}

// CTO.java
public class CTO extends DefaultBusinessman {
    // CTO does no longer need to be abstract, as the implementation of doWork is provided
    // through inheritance
}
```

Comment: Tnank you! The task I've beed solving accepted the following answer:
`
    public static class DefaultBusinessman implements Businessman {
        @Override
        public void workHard() {
        }
    } `

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free mark this answer as accepted if you think it solved you problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create CTO as abstract and dont have to implement Businessman

```
     public abstract class CTO implements Businessman {}

     public class specificCTO extends CTO {
         @Override
         public void workHard() {
         }

     }
```